# Getting Object required error on .Find method

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Compile Object Required when running a `.Find` on the following.
Data has been generated from a form and the code is within the form.
I have highlighted in blue where I get the error.

```vb
Dim MODATT As String
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim searchcell As String
Dim NewModShort As String
Dim MakeVal As String
Dim ModVal As String
Dim mdAtt As String


Private Sub ADDPROD_Click()
    Worksheets("SKU List").Activate
    SKUNUMBER = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value + 1
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = SKUNUMBER
    MODATT = Make.Value & " " & Model.Value & " " & PS.Value & "PS"

    With Worksheets("Model Att").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        Set mdAtt = .Find(What:=MODATT, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If mdAtt Is Nothing Then
            Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = MODATT
            MODATT.PutInClipboard
            MsgBox "Please add " & MODATT & "to the Model Attributes (This has been copied, ready to paste)", , "Add Attribute"
            ModShort
        Else
            ModShort
        End If

End Sub
```

`Set mdAtt =` gets the error:

> Compile Error: Object Required

Comment: You've declared `mdAtt` as a string variable. Use `Dim mdAtt As Range` instead. You need to have an object to use the `Set` method.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- As @Dean stated, you have `mdAtt` declared as a `String`. Declare is as a [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)). Then using the [`set` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) will work as `Range` is an object.
- Try to [declare variables where they are used](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#declare-variables-where-used) and indent your code. This would make your code easier to follow and debug.
- `SKUNUMBER` is never declared (at least in the code you provided). Use [Option Explicit](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#use-option-explicit) to help prevent this.
- Your `With` block is missing an `End With` which will give you a compile error.
- Your call to `ModShort` is at the end of your `If` as well as in your `Else` statement. Why not just removed the `Else` and run this after your `If` statement is complete?

```
If mdAtt Is Nothing Then
    ' ...
End If
ModShort
```